# How to download Spring platform in its official websit?

Tags: spring, download

The official websit of spring is : http://www.springframework.org/

but I can not find the download link.

why the official website dont put a download link? unspeakable..

Comment: http://spring.io/projects probably what you looking for is "Spring Framework"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the offical page for the spring framework

http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

Pivotal recommends that you download the Spring framework using a dependency management tool such as gradle or maven and they provide the configuration for both in that link. This is due to the fact that trying to manage the plethora of external dependencies that the spring framework has would be very awkward without such a tool.

**Edit** 
This link provides a bit more information for you..
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Downloading-Spring-artifacts

If you absolutely must, you can download the binary zip for each version from here...
http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/

Comment: thanks， but never heard about maven or gradle, and I still can not find the link goes to maven or gradle.

Comment: i edited my answer a bit there to give more information and a link that better describes the download process. It gives links to maven, gradle and ivy in that link also.

Comment: I found a link for the zipped distributions so ive added that to the answer too if you decide you want to do it that way (not my recommendation though!)